# getting error while calling sowflake external function from one database to another database

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-task

I have created a external function in one database and calling that function in another database.
am getting error as internal server error.

Do we have any limitation on calling snowflake external function accorss the database.

I called the function with fully qualified name.

Thanks,
Kumar

Comment: Nope, shouldn't be any limitation.  Does it work fine if you call it within that database/schema?  If not confidential, can you share some of the function at all or example SQL in how you are calling it?

Comment: Thanks I fixed that issue.The issue because of the search path. I have missed to set the search path. Once done its worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Answering for completeness (curating the tags):

This issue was resolved by setting the search path correctly.